# PAW Rest Client- Missing Image content in generated Javascript Code

Tags: paw-app

I am using Paw Rest client that is supposed to generate the Javascript (jQuery) code for the HTTP PUT request I am using to send File (Image) in the body. 
I have my Header as

```
"Content-Type:image/jpeg", Body as "File"
```

In the generated Javascript code, the image content is missing!!  See picture. 
Can anyone provide me the code so that I am able to send HTTP PUT request using html/javascript.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  To help you, I have added the image inline for you.  However, this is not satisfactory.  It would be preferable if you cut and pasted the text here.

Answer (score 0):

Paw tries to generate the code at best, and doesn't handle all edge cases. Sadly, files/image sending isn't implemented in the code generation for JavaScript... but here's a way to send a file content:

```
var fileContent = null; // file content comes here

// My API (PUT http://198.11.232.156/oslc/so/triWorkTaskRS/127368846/spi:cstImageIM)

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://198.11.232.156/oslc/so/triWorkTaskRS/127368846/spi:cstImageIM",
    type: "PUT",
    headers: {
        "Cookie": "JSESSIONID=...",
        "Authorization": "Basic ...",
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
    },
    processData: false,
    data: fileContent,
})
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("HTTP Request Succeeded: " + jqXHR.status);
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("HTTP Request Failed");
})
.always(function() {
    /* ... */
});
```

Now to retrieve a file's content in a web browser, you probably want to use the HTML5 `FileReader`. Here's an interesting answer for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29176118/1698645